# How to Create RFC Mail Format with Attachment?

Tags: php, pear

I have a problem with creating an RFC mail format with attachment. Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachments are made in multipart email format. You better use some lib to do it. But if you want to manage it yourself you need to create a document separated by multipart bounaries, that contains files in base64 encoding:

First, email headers:

```
To: admin@example.com
Subject: hi, admin!
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="some_random_string"
```

Than body:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
some_random_string
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
<p>Email text and image</p>
<img src="cid:attached_image">

some_random_string
Content-Type: image/png;name="some.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <attached_image> //<- this used in CID
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="some.png"
//here goes base64 encoded image.
```

There are some example function in php.net. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am trying it.

Comment: My project need to use Net_IMAP from PEAR. In that lib, function Net_IMAP::appendMessage($rfc_message) requires only $rfc_message. I think that rfc_message contain both header and body in one. The problem is i still cannot build message like this.
Pleaase help me!

Comment: As I see in docs appendMessage returns "Pear_Error" object. Try to `var_dump` it. I mean this: `$n = new Net_IMAP( ... your params here ... ); ... var_dump($n->appendMessage(...));`

Comment: Now I could do it.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer To use phpmailer library,which is free and available for download.Then something along these lines should help you.

```
require_once("PHPMailer.class.php");                                                                $mail=  new PHPMailer();                                                                               $mail->IsHTML(true); 


                $mail->Host ='Your Hostname';
                $mail->AddAddress($clientaddress);

                $mail->From = $email;
                $mail->FromName = $name;
                $mail->Subject = "Your Subject";
                $mail->AddAttachment($path);
                $mail->Body=$msg;       

                $mail->Send();
```